# How to change register colors in gnucash 3.x?

Tags: gnucash

I upgraded from gnucash v2.4 to 3.4 and I read the colors theme are gone... and to follow the instruction in "https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/GTK3#Register_Appearance" to change them in v3.4. So I thought I did:

1. I got the sample file from "https://github.com/Gnucash/gnucash/blob/maint/doc/gtk-3.0.css"
2. I disabled "Use GnuCash built-in color theme" in gnucash (the register looks black font on white background, header is greyish background)
3. Copy "gtk-3.0.css" to "C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Roaming\GnuCash"
4. Re-started gnucash

Theses lines below (from "gtk-3.0.css") makes me think that the register header should be seagreen:

/* Register User Colors */
.header-color {background-color: seagreen;color: white;}

I don't see any changes in the color of anything. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This might be a better question for StackOverflow, or one of the other stackexchange sites.